# Why is it showing Clang error 1 on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang, macos-big-sur

I started with a simple program to test if my vscode is running properly on my MacBook Air with BigSur OS. The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello");
   return 0;
}
```

But this error is coming:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
   "_main", referenced from:
    implicit entry/start for main executable.  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.  
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

What are the steps do I need carryout so that this simple piece of code runs?

Comment: No repro on Clang 7: see [here](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/BurlywoodPrestigiousVariable#main.c)

Comment: `uname_m` in the shell reports `x86_64`.

Comment: Have you [configured VSCode for Clang?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: Yes I configured and tried again but still the same

Comment: Does it work if you invoke clang directly?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that you have correctly configured VSC properly following this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp).

There is a lot involved with generating and editing your `tasks.json` / `launch.json` files, and if you don't do it correctly you might run into problems.

If you are willing to take a shortcut, you can alwayas install the VS [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension which will take care of much of the hassle for you and enable you to run codes with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: I have installed that extension upon installation. But still the problem persists.

Comment: Which "that" extension? `C/C++ for Visual Studio Code` or `Code Runner` ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are a beginner the simplest solution is to reconfigure your vscode. [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhGnYWplLVo) to see how to configure VSCode for C/C++ step-by-step.

Comment: The tutorial link is for windows. Even after configuring vscode with all extentions, its still showing the same error.

Comment: I updated the link. You have to configure your settings.json or task.json files. It will be messy for you as you are beginner. Simply uninstall VSCode and Follow the Link Above step by step. There will be no issues.